# C++ SFML text getLocalBounds() causes text to disappear

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm currently attempting to center text for a little school project I'm working on, but whenever I even call text.getLocalBounds(), it makes the text disappear.
[image: This is without getLocalBounds()]
The image above is without using getLocalBounds(), but when I even call it once... 
[image]
Is there some strange side effect of the getLocalBounds() function?  getGlobalBounds() also causes this, but not getPosition... any suggestions?

Comment: This shouldn't really happen. Can you try to reduce the problem to a minimal example and add that to your question? It's not really useful to try to type your code from screenshots (plus the line shouldn't really cause this issue). Also which version of SFML are you using?

Comment: I have the same issue happening on mingw with the newest ( as of ~ a month ago ) sfml version.  I will attempt to create a minimal example soon.  My linux sfml is up to date

Comment: It's strange, getBounds are const methods, they cannot change anything. But what is the type of probTokenLable object?

Comment: It is a sf::Text object, so I have no clue what the issue is...

Comment: @TehCosmicSloth actually getGlobalBounds shouldn't change anything, but there are some mutable members which can be changed during this method execution, but it needs debugging with SFML-sources.